# Corruption of data when trying to replace a part of the link in excel file

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, openpyxl

I am trying to write a code that will recursively go through a folder on the local drive, find *.xlsx and *.xls files, scan for links and replace part of the link with a input text...

I'm new to Python... It's like my 2th day...
Please help

What I'm trying to do is in fact to replace a part of the link with the input given by the user...
I tried with this code but It seems like I'm doing something wrong...
The output file gets corrupted meaning excel can't open it.

Those are linked values, links between the sheets.

For example A link as shown in the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ncBb.png).

```
='Z:\FINANCE\link synk test\Some Other Folder\[Document 2.xlsx]Sheet1'!$B$8
```

[Execution with params](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KLW3P.png)

When the script is executed I get the corrupted excel as an output;

[Error from Excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xudvi.png)

[Corupted links](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dT39Y.png)

```
import os
import openpyxl

FileDIR = input( "Folder: " )
ReplaceMe = input( "Replace: " )
ReplaceWith = input( "With: " )

FileCounter=0
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(FileDIR):
    for file in files:
        
        XLSXFileDIR = os.path.join(root, file)
        
        if file.lower().endswith(('.xlsx', '.xls')):
            
            FileCounter = FileCounter+1
            
            wb=openpyxl.load_workbook(XLSXFileDIR)
            
            links=wb._external_links
            
            LinkCounter=0
            for index, item in enumerate(links):
                Mystr =wb._external_links[index].file_link.Target
                Mystr=Mystr.replace("file:///","")
                Mystr=Mystr.replace("%20"," ")
                
                Mystr=Mystr.replace(ReplaceMe,ReplaceWith)
                
                LinkCounter=LinkCounter+1
                print("Link to: "+Mystr+" Found in: "+file)
            
            wb.save(os.path.join(root, "NEW_"+file))
            
print (str(FileCounter)+" Excel Files scaned /"+str(LinkCounter)+" Links found")
```

-------------- Update ------------------

A quick update. I tried something silly (code below)

```
from openpyxl.workbook import Workbook from openpyxl import load_workbook
File = "sampleexcel.xlsx"
create workbook object wb = Workbook()
create active worksheet ws = wb.active
load spredsheet wb = load_workbook(File)
get the stupid links links = wb._external_links
wb.save(File)
```

This makes no changes to the xlsx file but I still get an error when trying to open it indicating the file corruption....

Is there anything in "openpyxl" that makes it incompatible with excel/office 365 etc?????

---------- UPDATE -----------------
31/03/2023

This issue (file corruption) happens **ONLY if the xlsx file contains external links**. Those are not stored in the cell values and it seems openpyxl is not able to process them.

Code below:

```
import os
from openpyxl.workbook import Workbook
from openpyxl import load_workbook

#file location
FileDIR = r".\\"
File = "sampleexcel.xlsx"
### Create a list of files in the entered directory that end with '.xlsx'
files = [f for f in os.listdir(FileDIR) if f.endswith('.xlsx')]

#create workbook object
wb = Workbook()

#create active worksheet
ws = wb.active

#load spredsheet
wb = load_workbook(File)

#get the stupid links
links = wb._external_links

for index, item in enumerate(links):
    linkTarget = wb._external_links[index].file_link.Target       
    linkType = wb._external_links[index].file_link.Type
    print(linkTarget)
    print(linkType)
    
for row in wb:
    for cell in row:
        for value in cell:
            print (f'Cell: {value} value is: {value.value}')
```

Outpoot

```
file:///Z:\FINANCE\link%20synk%20test\Some%20Other%20Folder\Document%202.xlsx
http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/externalLinkPath
file:///Z:\FINANCE\link%20synk%20test\Some%20Folder\Document1.xlsx
http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/externalLinkPath
Cell: <Cell 'Employees'.A1> value is: None
Cell: <Cell 'Employees'.B1> value is: None
Cell: <Cell 'Employees'.C1> value is: None
Cell: <Cell 'Employees'.A2> value is: asd
Cell: <Cell 'Employees'.B2> value is: asd
Cell: <Cell 'Employees'.C2> value is: sd
Cell: <Cell 'Test'.A1> value is: Test
Cell: <Cell 'Test'.B1> value is: 1
Cell: <Cell 'Test'.C1> value is: None
Cell: <Cell 'Test'.D1> value is: =[1]Sheet1!$B$6
Cell: <Cell 'Test'.A2> value is: LALALA
Cell: <Cell 'Test'.B2> value is: 2
Cell: <Cell 'Test'.C2> value is: None
Cell: <Cell 'Test'.D2> value is: =[1]Sheet1!$B$7
Cell: <Cell 'Test'.A3> value is: I love trains
Cell: <Cell 'Test'.B3> value is: 3
Cell: <Cell 'Test'.C3> value is: None
Cell: <Cell 'Test'.D3> value is: =[1]Sheet1!$B$3
Cell: <Cell 'Test'.A4> value is: None
Cell: <Cell 'Test'.B4> value is: =SUM(B1:B3)
Cell: <Cell 'Test'.C4> value is: None
Cell: <Cell 'Test'.D4> value is: =[2]Sheet1!$B$7
```

The file I get as output after simply opening and saving to a NEW_*.xlsx appears smaller in size suggesting data being lost in the process

The code I run to open and save as NEW_*.xlsx

```
File = "sampleexcel.xlsx"
wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active
wb = load_workbook(File)
wb.save("NEW_"+File)
```

I'm running: Openpyxl version is 3.1.2. Python version is 3.11.2

1. I have checked on 2 Win PCs,
2. I have asked my friend to run this in his environment.
3. I have checked on various excel files

Comment: @moken Thanks again... I have updated the original question with some trials I did... As suspected I get the file corruption even if not making ANY changes to it.. just opening and saving it... I suspect there is a bug I'm not taking into account...

Comment: No issue I'm aware of with Openpyxl that would corrupt the file like this with xlsx files. Do you have the latest version of Openpyxl installed? current release is 3.1.2. You can confirm the version used by your code by adding the line **print(openpyxl.__version__)** .

Comment: Hi @moken I also found this https://foss.heptapod.net/openpyxl/openpyxl/-/issues/1992

Comment: Openpyxl does not create an xlsx files with every sub file that Excel uses . So if you create an xlsx file with Openpyxl then open that file in Excel and save without making any changes you will see the file is larger than before opening it. This should not be an issue

Comment: Sure but the problem is that the file created in excel 365 (sampleexcel.xlsx) is 12KB I am opening this file using the commands above and saving it as (NEW_sampleexcel.xlsx) the output file (NEW_sampleexcel.xlsx) has a size of 7KB!!! the data are lost and the file becomes unreadable... I have no experience to be 100% sure about this, BUT, To me, it seems to indicate a BUG in openpyxl

Comment: I tried running your updated code (Thanks for this by the way). Unfortunately, this same thing happens...

Comment: I did try opening the files I created new with online office 365 and again no issues opening the files. OOXML has its problems so per the link you provided its possible changes to either may be causing your issues now. Not sure there is more I can suggest maybe your workbook would work for me and may be not. You might want to consider Xlwings instead if running Excel is not an issue (appears you are on Win). Xlwings is the python VBA for Excel and would do this differently.

Comment: Otherwise certainly you can raise this issue with the Devs on foss.heptapod (they don't use github) be prepared to provide a sample of the sheet.

Comment: Yeah, just to be clear, I'm not having any problems writing into the Excel cell values or hyperlinks etc. I'm using Local 365 Excel but I fail to see how this would make difference. Anyway... Once again thank you for everything you did...

Answer (score 0):

Updated code from your additional details.
Since they are not hyperlinks the code uses your original command

```
links = wb._external_links
```

to obtain the links, so no need for checking individual cells.

As before, in your code example there is nowhere that you are updating the links with the text replacements in the variable `Mystr` so the code just saves the same workbook with a new name. I don't see how it could end up corrupted.
Indeed with your updated information I ran your code on two example workbooks and the resultant files were able to be opened without error. The links of course had **not** changed from `FINANCE` to `LALALA` as would be expected.
The test links in the sheets used were of a similar format to the example in the question. Otherwise the issue may be something external. You might need to try to compare the new files makeup with the originals before opening in Excel to see if you can determine why.

The updated code example below implements some of the suggested changes again as well as including the line

```
links[index].file_link.Target = Mystr
```

to update the links with the replacement values.

Other comments on the code

1. Openpyxl only supports xlsx files. You cannot open or modify `xls` files in any way and attempting to open any would just return a `not a zip file` error.
2. Incrementing a counter is usually done with `+=` so FileCounter increment should be;

   FileCounter += 1
3. There are two counters in in the `links` loop, LinkCounter and index, that do the same thing. You just use `index` in the loop and sum with LinkCounter as each file is processed for the over all link count.
4. I dont think a link will ever include the text `file:///`. That is internal to Excel as an indicator to a file so a link will never contain it.

The following code example will do what your code appears to be attempting.
It modifies your code incorporating the comments listed above.

1. Creates a list of `xlsx' files in your directory to loop through.
2. Moves FileCounter as an enumerator starting at '1'
3. Iterates the files loop and accesses `wb.external_links`
4. Creates loop to update link targets
5. After all links are modified the file is saved as `NEW_<file name>`
6. Next file is processed as above
7. File and link count is printed using f string

Code Example

```
import os
import openpyxl

FileDIR = input("Folder: ")
ReplaceMe = input("Replace: ")
ReplaceWith = input("With: ")

FileCounter = 0
LinkCounter = 0

### Create a list of files in the entered directory that end with '.xlsx'
files = [f for f in os.listdir(FileDIR) if f.endswith('.xlsx')]

### Loop the files list to process each file. Include FileCounter starting at value 1
for FileCounter, file in enumerate(files, 1):

    XLSXFileDIR = os.path.join(FileDIR, file)

    ### Open the file in Openpyxl
    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(XLSXFileDIR)

    ### Get file links
    links = wb._external_links

    ### Loop links
    for index, item in enumerate(links):
        Mystr = links[index].file_link.Target

        ### Replace values
        Mystr = Mystr.replace("file:///", "")
        Mystr = Mystr.replace("%20", " ")

        Mystr = Mystr.replace(ReplaceMe, ReplaceWith)

        print("Link to: " + Mystr + " Found in: " + file)

        ### update the links with the new path after string replacements    
        links[index].file_link.Target = Mystr

    LinkCounter += index+1

    ### Save workbook to new name
    wb.save(os.path.join(FileDIR, "NEW_" + file))

### Print FileCounter and LinkCounter results using f string
print(f'{FileCounter} Excel Files scanned, {LinkCounter} Links found')
```

I created two sheets with links using the example shown `='Z:\FINANCE\link synk test\Some Other Folder\[Document 2.xlsx]Sheet1'!$B$8` and using `FINANCE` for `ReplaceMe` and `LALALA` for `ReplaceWith`. This produced two new sheets as expected which opened without error and the path had been updated from `FINANCE` to `LALALA`.
To repeat this same test was performed using your code before and after adding the line

```
links[index].file_link.Target = Mystr
```

This also produced uncorrupted xlsx files.

Comment: Also.....I see 
Another thing is that I'm getting same issue when only opening and saving the *.xlsx file 

#create workbook object
wb = Workbook()

#create active worksheet
ws = wb.active

#load spredsheet
wb = load_workbook(File)